Unable to ssh from Mac to Ubuntu 24.10 on same wifi network
New Details

Another Mac on the same network, with the same OS exactly, and supposedly the same in every way, does not have this problem
I rebuilt the Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 22.04

Here is the scenario:

Raspberry Pi 3B+ installed with brand new Ubuntu 22.04 server
Successfully connects to home wifi
MacOS is able to see the Pi via LanScan and shows IP address 192.168.5.75
Wifi network is on eero
Eero has extra security, add blocking, etc all turned off
Eero had been fully rebooted
Connecting Pi with direct ethernet does not help
MacOs has a successful trace route to same:

~ traceroute 192.168.5.75
traceroute to 192.168.5.75 (192.168.5.75), 64 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  192.168.5.75 (192.168.5.75)  11.065 ms  8.323 ms  11.476 ms

And yet I am unable to ping or ssh to that same ip address:
~ ping 192.168.5.75
PING 192.168.5.75 (192.168.5.75): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1

~ ssh -vvv pitosalas@192.168.5.75
OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/pitosalas/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.5.75 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/pitosalas/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/pitosalas/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: channel_clear_timeouts: clearing
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.5.75 [192.168.5.75] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: connect to address 192.168.5.75 port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host 192.168.5.75 port 22: No route to host
~

Here is the local ssh you requested:

Now the local ssh with the ip address. It worked without error. And in the image you can see the tail end of the ssh -vvv for the name and ip address in case that tell sou something...

Checked so far

ssh service running
ufw is off
Fails with wired ethernet as well as wifi


Can you locally login to the Ubuntu server (Raspberry Pi) terminal? If so, does ssh username@127.0.0.1 work? If it works try ssh username@192.168.5.75 from within the server. Edit your question with the new information.

thanks @user68186 - See above for the test. I put in an image so you could see the rest of the output after a login in case that contains a clue of some kind.

If you can't ping the server and output says No route to host, I would first check the routing tables on the Mac. If that looks good, then check the router. If you can't ping the server, you won't be able to SSH to it. So first things first.

Also, your screenshot indicates you're using 24.10. Please edit your post to correct this

And as @user68186 requested, please add the results of ssh pitosalas@192.168.5.75

24.10! Not whet I meant to install. Could it be that?
Also the ssh pitosalas@192.168.5.75 worked without error. See above.

Firewall on Mac has no rules against this. And if I turn it off in the Mac UI the problem does not go away. Also see a few small details at the top about my wifi network. Even though connecting with a wired ethernet does not help.

Could it be the 24.10 Ubuntu. Should I start over with 24.04 by any chance?

The Ubuntu version should be fine. The fact that ssh works locally, proves that the Ubuntu side is working. The ping failing points to routing problem either in the Mac or in the router. If ping does not work, the does not "see" the IP address. So ssh won't work either.

By testing from another Mac on the network, you've proven that the problem is not with the Ubuntu server.

I agree. It is something on the Mac. I am creating a clean new question focusing on the Mac,

I safe booted the Mac and the problem goes away. However, even after turning off all startup items and doing a non-safe boot, the problem remains. This is now a Mac problem

You've established that SSH works on the server, both on localhost and on 192.168.5.75. Furthermore, you've stated that UFW firewall is off. So the problem is not with your Ubuntu server.
The problem lies with either your Mac, router, or network configuration.
Therefore, you need to look at the routing tables on the Mac, inspect the router configuration, and verify your physical network setup.
If you solve the problem of connecting to the Ubuntu server first by achieving a successful ping 192.168.5.75 from the Mac, then connecting via SSH will work.

You mentioned in your question that you're using eero. With a quick search, I found the following link, which indicates that SSH is blocked. So I would check that as well.
eero Firewall - why some ports closed vs. stealth'd?

I will ask eero support. But I think that link talks about ssh from outside my network to inside. This scenario is obviously inside to inside. Also I've had this work for other raspberry pis. The only differences I can think of are: the version of Ubuntu and the fact that my Mac recently updated to the latest point release.
